# Snap.svg drag grouped items by points

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

i have a problem with snap.svg drag. I have two grouped rectangles on the top of this image. So i need to drag a red rectangle to get a result like the bottom of the picture.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9HcF.png)

Comment: Please share a code example so we can see what's going on

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/c861um5d/1/

Comment: I think include whatever code you have, it's not clear from your question.